# Mongo user and password do not get set on docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"


volumes:
  mongodb-data:
    name: mongodb-data

networks:
  mongodb_network:
    name: mongodb_network


services:

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.4.5-bionic
    container_name: mongodb
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: provider
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
      - mongodb-data:/data/db
    networks:
      - mongodb_network
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongo 10.10.10.60:27017/test --quiet
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 10s
```

When I try to log in after the container has started with the user `admin` and password `admin` it shows in the console:

```
"ctx":"conn9","msg":"Authentication failed","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","principalName":"admin","authenticationDatabase":"admin","client":"172.21.0.1:43142","result":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"admin\" for db \"admin\""}} 

"ctx":"conn9","msg":"Authentication failed","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-1","principalName":"admin","authenticationDatabase":"provider","client":"172.21.0.1:43142","result":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"admin\" for db \"provider\""}}
```

I tried to log in with DataGrip and it complained:
[image]

I have figured out when login without a user and password then it works:
[image]

It seems that user and password do not get set by environment variables properly.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) regarding the use of these environment variables?  This part might be of particular interest: ***"Do note that none of the variables below will have any effect if you start the container with a data directory that already contains a database: any pre-existing database will always be left untouched on container startup."***

Comment: Does that mean I have to delete the volume and start the container again?

Comment: Or do I have to do to make it work? I have deleted the volume and still the authentication does not work.

Comment: Yes, if the volume exists with a database in it the mongo image does not create the user/pass. If you `rm`'d the volume, you should edit your question to include that as something you tried. Be sure you actually removed it. Since it was created with `docker-compose` you will not be able to remove it with `docker volume rm -f`. Check the docs RE `MONGO_INITDB_DATBASE`, specifically: *"allows you to specify the name of a database to be used for creation scripts in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*.js` ... if you do not insert data with your JavaScript files, then **no database is created**."*